# string in alphabetical order

Tags: c++, string, sorting, loops

i m trying to print the string in alphabetical order using recursive functions, but it gives a string subscript out of range error.

```
string alpha(string word)
{
    char temp;
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while (count < word.size())
    {
        if (word[i] > word[i + 1])
        {
            temp = word[i];
            word[i] = word[i + 1];
            word[i + 1] = temp;
            i++;
            if (i >= word.size())
            {
                alpha(word);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return word;
}
```

Comment: Why not use `std::sort` ?

Comment: The issue is `word[i + 1]`. When your `i` gets to the max index, that pushes you outside of it.

Comment: cause i want to make a function

Comment: `while (count < word.size() - 1)
 {
  i++;

  if (word[i] > word[i + 1])
  {
   temp = word[i];
   word[i] = word[i + 1];
   word[i + 1] = temp;
 
  }

  else if (i >= word.size())
  {
   alpha(word);
  }
  else
  {
   count++;
  }
 }
  
   return word;
 
    }` @JonThemon

Comment: Even if you do make your own function, there's absolutely no reason to inline swapping instead of using `std::swap`. By the way, this is not alphabetical order. "ABab" should not remain that way.

Comment: @T-man the simplest (and arguably the most memory/cpu inefficient) algorithm I can think of for simple-recursive bubble-sort is [something like this](http://ideone.com/Mja8qT). It would be better with iterators, but for studying recursion, its good enough. The real-world would simply use `std::sort` with a lexicographical comparator, but I doubt that was what you were aiming at. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Because you use `if (word[i] > word[i + 1])` you must stop your loop one prior to the end... and you need `count` or `i` (not both); that is

```
while (i + 1 < word.size()) // <-- like so
```

or you could use

```
int i = 1;
while (i < word.size()) {
  if (word[i - 1] > word[i]) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do that way:

```
std::string alpha(std::string s)
{
    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());
    return s;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/P9MWub)

If you want to implement yourself a `O(n²)` sort algorithm, you may do:

```
std::string alpha(std::string word)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != word.size(); ++i) {
        for (std::size_t j = i + 1; j != word.size(); ++j) {
            if (word[j] < word[i]) {
                std::swap(word[i], word[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return word;
}
```

or a resursive one:

```
std::string alpha(std::string word)
{
    auto it = std::is_sorted_until(word.begin(), word.end());

    if (it == word.end()) {
        return word;
    }
    std::size_t i = std::distance(word.begin(), it);
    do {
        std::swap(word[i], word[i - 1]);
        --i;
    } while (i > 1 && word[i] < word[i - 1]);
    return alpha(word);
}
```